# how do i make rubymine for rails debugger work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

When I run the debugger in rubymine  im getting that server log below so it  seems to be working, but when i go this path http://127.0.0.1:51271 stays loading, so I dont know if this is the right way to use the debugger,  so how can I make the debugger start working?

```
 /home/developer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p647/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 51271 --dispatcher-port 55708 -- /home/developer/linux-shared/projects/apps/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
    Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, debase 0.2.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 127.0.0.1:51271
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 4.1.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    I, [2015-10-28T09:59:32.438087 #11696]  INFO -- : ** [Bugsnag] Bugsnag exception handler 2.5.1 ready, api_key=432a2b27ce528437b2f65848a370856c
    [2015-10-28 09:59:33] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    [2015-10-28 09:59:33] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
    [2015-10-28 09:59:33] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11696 port=3000
```

by the way if i enter to http://0.0.0.0:3000  the application enters but the brakpoints never gets triggered

Answer (score 0):

It may be issue of debugging gems in your Gemfile.